# How to install new git hook to all existing (cloned) repositories?

Tags: git, githooks

I have ~50 repositories on my machine. I would like to install newly created git hook to all of them.

I've already created `.git-templates` folder and put hooks there, then `git config --global init.templatedir ~/.git-templates` - it works for new repositories but what about existing ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you use a recent version of `git` (>= 2.9), then I would recommend using the `core.hooksPath` variable.

Then you can create a separate directory where you put all your hooks, eg `/var/myhooks`, then

```
git config --global core.hooksPath /var/myhooks
```

would make this directory the default hooks directory for all your repositories at once. As a side effect, all hooks under `.git/hooks` in each repository will be ignored. But inside a specific repository, you could then override this again with its own hooks directory:

```
git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.  Find all the repositories and copy the hooks.  Here's a sample (this might find more than you think, it's why the actual copy gets echoed not executed, don't just c&p the echoed commands if you might have `'`'s in your pathnames):

```
find ~ -name HEAD -execdir test -f config -a -d objects -a -d refs \; \
        -execdir mkdir -p hooks \; \
        -printf "cp -a ~/.git-templates/hooks '%h'/hooks\\n"
```